# Loop <audio> on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html, audio

I have the player, that should loop sound automaticly endless times6 while not stopping.
Here is his initial (cofeescript):

```
    @audio = $("<audio><source src='#{@getAudioUrl()}' type='audio/mpeg' /></audio>").appendTo(@vb)
    @audio.on("ended", => @audio.currentTime=0; @audio.play())
    @audio = @audio.get(0)
```

It correctly work in all desktop browsers, but when this player is emedded via iframe to the page and opened by th any mobile browser - it stopped after 2-10 loops.
What can be the matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using an  tag anyway, why don't you just use the built-in HTML loop function?

```
<audio loop><source src='#{@getAudioUrl()}' type='audio/mpeg' /></audio>
```

Notice the 'loop' within the audio tag.